# springSecurityService returns a null user on load

Tags: grails, spring-security

Occasionally this code returns a null user object (line 1), even though the springSecurityService.principal.id is a valid id.  Line 2 throws a null pointer exception because the user object is null.  Most of the time the code works, but I can't figure out what causes the null load.

1. User user = User.load(springSecurityService.principal.id)
2. def contactInstance = BasicProfile.findByUser(user)

Attached is a screenshot of the user object after the call in line1.

[image]

Could it be due to a timeout in the session?  And if so why wouldn't the controller get redirected to the login page if that were the case?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with Tomcat caching some data incorrectly.

Here is what I did:

1. Stopped Tomcat
2. Deleted all the files in Tomcat's Temp directory
3. Restarted Tomcat

After that, it worked fine.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes if I stop and restart the server it fixes everything.  However when I go into production that's not going to be a good option.  I'd like to avoid the problem or else who knows how often I'll need to restart the server to fix it.

Comment: I've only had this happen 2 or 3 times in the past 3 years for me, so maybe put this in the maintenance??  That's about all I can think of because it seems to be more related to Tomcat than Grails.

Comment: It happens about a dozen times every day to me during my development.

Comment: @user2636133 I just found this post and maybe it will help you if you have not already resolved the problem: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/acegi-authenticateService-userDomain-returns-out-of-date-object-bug-td2260781.html